# Unable to access TFS 2010 from VS 2012 across a different domain

Tags: tfs

I have created a TFS project collection and a Team Project, I also have a Team Project \ Group undyer which I've added all team project users.  TFS is controlled by Domain B and users will try to connect to TFS from Domain A.  all TFS users have both Domain A and Domain B accounts.

When I try to connect to TFS from a machine in Domain A I get prompted for Domain B credentials the credentials popup pos twice or three times before I get an error message saying "no account information is provided..."

any idea on what TFS (Team Project or Team collection) Group shoud my users be added to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your own new group to the TeamProject group that is called "Project Collection Valid Users", otherwise they are not allowed to acces the TFS.